# Column-major array storage in C compilers

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, clang, icc

Are there any C compilers that have extensions to store an array in column-major order instead of the standard row-major order?

Comment: What you exactly mean? It's not clear.

Comment: @Frankie_C He wants a fortran style array.

Comment: You can make your own column major matrix class in C++ with the right operator overloading. You can overload `operator()` to get the exact same behaviour as fortran.

Comment: In pure C you can use a plain function call. I'm not aware of compiler support for column major accessing. That will actually break the very basis of C/C++ grammar for pointer dereferencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is "No".

Long answer is that storing an array in column-major order would break the one-to-one correspondence between array index operations and pointer arithmetics, and the way an N-dimension array is sliced into N-1 dimension arrays.

Consider a 10x20 array stored in column-major order. This means that cells in adjacent columns would be next to each other in memory. On the other hand, converting a pointer to array element at i, j to an element pointer must work like this:

```
int *p=&a[1][5];
int *q=&a[1][6];
p++;
```

The standard requires that p is equal q, because the two pointers point to adjacent elements. This would not be possible if array a were stored in column-major order.

In C you would have to write your own set of functions to work with such arrays. If you code in C++, however, you would have an option to implement your own multi-dimension array, and overload the parentheses operator () to work in a column-major order.

Comment: It's a better idea to overload (override?) `operator()` than `operator[]`, as you can accept more than one operands.

Comment: @xiver77 thanks, that's an excellent point. Row vs col major matters only for multi-dimension arrays anyway.

Comment: There's no inherent reason to treat arrays as a[y][x], you could as well, consistently treat them as a[x][y] and as long as you do, the memory is layed out as expected, since the square brackets when accessing it are basically just syntax sugar, afaiu.

Comment: What would be lacking is a type annotation or otherwise type system support for the distinction between row and column major arrays, at least in c (In c++ you could create two different "type" classes to disallow mixing etc.)

Comment: To clarify my point - There's no built in column or row major concept or preference into the language itself, as I understand it. And it is this point that I think should be made clear as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Guest86 The standard requires certain behaviors when you chop off the last index. Sure, one can implement the same behavior when you chop off the first index, but that does more than simply changing the memory layout. It would be fair to call it a different language based on the syntax of C (there's nothing wrong with it, by the way: many such languages exist even today, i.e. they look almost like C, but the behavior is slightly different).

Comment: @Guest86 as for your last point, since there are no multi-dimension arrays in C, only arrays of arrays, the whole concept of rows and columns is a great deal in the mind of the reader. Call the first index a column - and you've just got yourself a column-major array :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes but if you consistently treat it throught the program as arr[x][y] or arr[x], you will get what you expect - The memory layout is the same but whether the first argument is a column or a row, isn't built in into the language. This `arr[x][y]` will just get translated to `*((int*)arr+x*V+y)` where `V` is the height instead of having `arr[y][x]` be `*((int*)arr+y*V+x)` where `V` is the width.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes that's exactly what I mean :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "in the mind of the reader" is a good point, I should have posed the question more abstractly -- perhaps something about the right-most indices striding the length of the left-most indices.